# how use RegEx in String.replaceAll for ignoring middle characters while searching and replacing

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I have to search in testFile.xml every word "abc" + 7 numbers not important + "myOldWord" to change to some new without worring the numbers inside. There will a couple of "xxx9999999myOldWorld". How can I find "abc1234567myOldWorld" and replace only myOldWorld for newWorld using regular expression? I can't only exchange from myOldWorld to newWord because the first three caracters have to be used in the search criteria an the unknown 7 lengths between them must be ignored.

Other example. Let us say I have the new world "aaaOtherNewWord" to replace "aaa9999999OtherOldWord" (I don't know the number when searching and there are a couple of them with different numbers). 
Let's say there are three old words in the testFile.xml: aaa1234567OTHEROLDWORD, aaa9876543otheroldword and bbb9876543otheroldword and I want to execute replaceAll and get the outcome: aaa1234567OtherNewWord and aaa9876543OtherNewWord respectvely but bbb9876543otheroldword will not change because the first 3 digits didn't match the search criteria.

I coded below and successfully I am ignoring the case when searching but I must ignore the numbers and I don't know how to do this with regular expression.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\testFolder\\testFile.xml");
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
content = content.replaceAll("(?i)" + oldWord, newWord);
```

Note: I am using Java 8.

The entire test is:

// C:\test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<c:bps xmlns:c="CertainApp">
<c:bp name="ProductPortfolio" id="myProdPort">

  <!-- must result in ABC1234567MyCompanyWORDProductSubproduct-->
  <c:message type="ABC1234567MyCompanyWorDProductSubproduct" /> 

  <!-- must result in ABC0987654MyCompanyWORDProductSubproduct-->
  <c:message type="ABC0987654MyCompanyWoRdProductSubproduct" />

  <!-- must result in XYZ1234567MyCompanywordproductSubproduct-->
  <c:message type="XYZ1234567MyCompanywOrdproductSubproduct" />

  <!-- nothing changed in next two-->
  <c:message type="XYZ1234567MyCompanyAnyThingproductSubproduct" />
  <c:message type="XYZ0987654MyCompanyAnyThingproductSubproduct" />
</c:bps>
```

//C:\defaults_test contains two files

```
ABCMyCompanyWORDproductSubproduct.xml  //here the “word” is uppercase and starts with ABC

XYZMyCompanywordproductSubproduct.xml  //here the “word” is lowercase and starts with XYZ

public class ReadICTTDefaultFolder {
       public static void replaceFileString(String first3letters, String word)  {
                     Path path = Paths.get("C:\\test.xml");
                     Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
                     try{
                           String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
                           content = content.replaceAll("((?i)" + first3letters + "\\d{7})" + word, "$1"+word);
                           Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
                     }
                     catch(Exception e){
                     }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           File actual = new File("C:\\ defaults_test");
           File list[] = actual.listFiles();

           for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
               String substring = list[i].getName().substring(0, list[i].getName().indexOf("."));

               if(list[i].isFile() && substring.toUpperCase().contains("WORD")){
                      replaceFileString(substring.substring(0,3), substring.substring(3));

               }
           }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
content = content.replaceAll("(abc\\d{7})" + oldWord, "$1"+newWord);
```

You can, in the replacement string, refer to a group via `$n` where `n` is the group number.

The regex part `\\d{7}` matches exactly seven *digits* (don't confuse this with numbers).

It would also be possible to pick the correct oldWord using a positive lookbehind assertion:

```
      replaceAll( "(?<=abc\\d{7})" + oldWord, newWord )
```

and then you don't need the $1.

**Later**

Now that I see the whole mess, where the "(?i)" is essential, I should have added that an option string must be written at the proper nesting level of parentheses:

```
 ...replaceAll("(?i)(" + prefix + "\\d{7})" + oldWord, "$1"+newWord);
```

and **not**

```
 ...replaceAll("((?i)" + prefix + "\\d{7})" + oldWord, "$1"+newWord);
```

which would restrict the case-ignoring match to the prefix. Since the prefix should, perhaps, match exactly, it would be best to write

```
 ...replaceAll("(" + prefix + "\\d{7})(?i)" + oldWord, "$1"+newWord);
```

As it seems, oldWord and newWord are identical except for case, you can also use

```
 ...replaceAll("(" + prefix + "\\d{7})(?i)" + word, "$1" + word);
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not working and I don't see errors when debuging:
content = content.replaceAll("(abc\\d{7})" + oldWord, "$1"+newWord);

Comment: Can you add the not-working test case to your Q? - I've tested it and it works, as shown in my A.

Comment: Please, remove the html comments inside test.xml if you are going to run. The comments tell you the result for WorDP, WoRd and wOrd respectvly (kindly note each character case for these three words. The business context is that everything goes fine in Windows but in Unix is different. I can't change the code to ignore the cases and I must change in test.xml to reflect exactly what I have in folder. I can't just make a simple replace because there are two more information in the names (first 3 letters and 7 numbers). The 7 numbers I have to keep but the letters come from the file name.

Comment: I hope I understood everything. I'm not sure about the missing "p" in XYZ1234567MyCompanywOrdroductSubproduct (**...ordrod...**). See update of my answer.

Comment: About "missing p", it was a typo. I fixed it. I deleted "p" letter accidentally.

Comment: I tested exactly now and it is working perfectly. Thanks. As a final doubt: is there a way to debug each expression step using Eclipse? Let's say you were sure that it was correct but it wasn't giving the expected result (please, accept this scenario). What do you do? If it was pure java I would debug in Eclipse. But what do you do with regexp?

Comment: There's no regex debugger I know of. But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886786/parse-log-with-regular-expression/27887199#27887199 for a good way to *compose* regexes from smaller ones which can be conveniently checked. And then you can exercise: http://regexcrossword.com/  ;-)